# Define value of a column by another column in Excel

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-excel-2010, worksheet-function

This seems like it should be so simple! I need to define column B by column A
If column A is equal to any value in the array "taco,burger,spaghetti" column B should read "food", if column A is equal to any value in the other array "dress,shoes,belt" column B should read "clothing" - but what formula can I use?

THANK YOU!

Answer (score 1):

<s>I'm not quite sure how to define a definite array within this formula</s>, but this will work if you change the `K1:K3` to a range that holds the items that are "food"

`=IF(ISERROR(MATCH(A1,K1:K3,0))=FALSE,"Food","")`

if you need to do it multiple times, just replace the final `""` with a new series of this checking for the value in a different list of *clothing*. Like this:

`=IF(ISERROR(MATCH(A1,K1:K3,0))=FALSE,"Food",IF(ISERROR(MATCH(A1,L1:L3,0))=FALSE,"Clothing",""))`

### EDIT

duh, you can define the array with curly brackets -

`=IF(ISERROR(MATCH(A1,{"taco","burger","spaghetti"},0))=FALSE,"Food",IF(ISERROR(MATCH(A1,{"dress","shoes","belt"},0))=FALSE,"Clothing",""))`

Answer (score 1):

You could go with Raystafarian's answer if you're not going to change your groups for "Food" or "Clothing."

I would recommend setting up a [table](http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/excel-help/overview-of-excel-tables-HA010048546.aspx) on another sheet to define your groups and using a lookup to translate. I'll skip the table for this answer, because it isn't necessary.

So, assuming that `A1` is the cell with "taco" or another such value in it, and columns `A` and `B` on `Sheet2` is your lookup table with "taco", "shoes", etc. in column `A` and `Food` and `Clothing` in column `B`, then put the following formula wherever you want the evaluation of `A1` to appear:

```
=IFERROR(VLOOKUP(A1,Sheet2!A:B,2,FALSE),"")
```

The `VLOOKUP` function looks for `A1` in the reference `Sheet2!A:B`, and returns column `2` from that reference. The `FALSE` tells it to find an exact match, rather than assuming that list is in order and that a close match is good enough.

The `IFERROR` function is just to catch values that you didn't put in the lookup table. If you want something else to happen, change `""`.

`Sheet2` should look like this:

```
   A         B
1  taco      Food
2  burger    Food
3  spaghetti Food
4  shoes     Clothing
5  dress     Clothing
6  belt      Clothing
```